# Convert date and time columns in a pandas df to a timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

i am new to python and used to code in R.
I have a Pandas df that has a column of dates and times.

```
                     date   time 
     0           2018-06-25  07:32:25    
     1           2018-06-25  09:36:38    
     2           2018-06-25  13:31:47   
     3           2018-06-25  13:29:56   
     4           2018-06-29  04:00:13
```

I used to select these columns and create numercial vectors to convert them into one vector of timestamps in R. Is there a possibility to do something similar in python? I already tried this:

```
strtime = df1['time'].astype(str)
strdate = df1['date'].astype(str)

timestamp = pd.to_datetime(strdate + ' ' + strtime)
```

But it gives me the output:

> "ValueError: Unknown string format"

I believe this might be an easy task so please be kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is problem some bad values, solution is parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert them to `NaT`:

```
timestamp = pd.to_datetime(strdate + ' ' + strtime, errors='coerce')
```

You can check these values by:

```
print (df1[pd.to_datetime(strdate + ' ' + strtime, errors='coerce').isnull()])
```